# Android Studio cannot complete post request

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to complete a simple `POST` request with Android Studios. I am new to Android Studios but not new to Java. I have this code working in Eclipse:

```
        String result = "";
        URL url = new URL("https://www.demo.com/test.php");
        String postData = "ID=220";

        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length()));

        try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {
            dos.writeBytes(postData);
        }

        try (BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream())))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

But when I run this in Android Studios and debug I get stuck on this line

`try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {`

The only error I can see is url = Cannot find local variable 'url' but it is local and clearly defined

[image]

I have tried adding this to my build.gradle

```
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = false
        }
```

"Enable auto expressions in Variables view" in settings

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` in my AndroidManifest.xml.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you ask for this permission
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> in the manifest as well?

Comment: Paste logcat info for future assistance becaue it has stack trace

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was doing this in Main Activity I needed to start an `AsyncTask` and do this in the background